# How do I delete rows of data from mysql table automatically with 24 hours after data into table?

Tags: php, mysql, jobs

For example, i have a data input program And I want to delete my data automatically after 1 day of this data I input. how I do that?
Someone can explain in code?

Create.php these values are sent to the server

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name_portofolio">
    <textarea name="info_portofolio"></textarea>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*"  name="picture_portofolio"> 
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

function-add.php

```
<?php

function create_data($name_portofolio, $info_portofolio,
                  $picture_portofolio)
{
   global $connect;
   $name_portofolio = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $name_portofolio);
   $info_portofolio = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $info_portofolio);


   $filePath = "picture/".basename($picture_portofolio["name"]);
   move_uploaded_file($picture_portofolio["tmp_name"], $filePath);

   $query = "INSERT INTO portofolio 
         (name_portofolio, info_portofolio, picture_portofolio) 
          VALUES ('$name_portofolio', '$info_portofolio', '$filePath')";

   if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
   {
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
  } // create_data
```

db.php

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "wherco";

// create connection
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

// check connection
if($connect->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed : " . $connect->connect_error);
} else {
    // echo "Successfully Connected";
}

?>
```

thanks .

Comment: use `cron jobs`

Comment: What is cron jobs?

Comment: @wawanD  [What is cron job](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-are-cron-jobs)

Comment: there is no special code for php and mysql for this?

Comment: @wawanD nope, unless you want to keep your script running 24/7 and that would be a waste of memory. So your best solution would be to use a cron job.

Comment: Does this really work? When I delete by detail, example "where status = 1"?

Comment: MySQL events work like charm for things such as this

Comment: It is possible to solve the question using only MySQL.

Comment: Please never use SQL queries like that, they are highly vulnerable for SQL injection

Answer (score 9):

Try to use regular events. To get started, enable the Event Scheduler using

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

After that you could [crate event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) that will check rows creation time. For example

```
CREATE EVENT recycling ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR ENABLE 
  DO 
  DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE `timestamp_column` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```

If there is no column with timestamp of a row creation in your table, then you can create trigger that will insert current timestamp and inserted row identificator to auxiliary table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER logCreator AFTER INSERT ON MainTable
  FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO LogTable (MainID, Created) VALUES(NEW.id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Then you can use this log to get keys of main table that was created before specific time.

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT cleaner ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR ENABLE 
  DO 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE MaxTime TIMESTAMP;
    SET MaxTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
    DELETE FROM MainTable 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT MainID FROM LogTable WHERE Created < MaxTime);
    DELETE FROM LogTable WHERE LogTable.Created < MaxTime;
  END |
  delimiter ;
```

Comment: @wawanD, is it possible to get feedback?.. Did the proposed answer solve your question?

Answer (score -1):

In your table "portofolio" add column created_at(datetime).
Then in Cron Job, check the current datetime exceeds created_at(datetime) with 24hours and delete the records by mysql query like

```
DELETE FROM portofolio WHERE created_at<=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

And run the cron job file every minute

Comment: Since mysql is running anyway and the operation shall be performed inside mysql i would use mysql so to not rely on another service (cron). Why would you recommend to use [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/)?