# Can database remove rows itself?

Tags: database, database-design

Can database remove rows itself with condition?

Usually I have removed data from database by user action, but now I want database to do it by itself. It should be able to delete rows with timestamp without user. Every time when row has older timestamp than NOW() it deletes itself.

Can anyone recommend any databases or (tools) for my project?

Tools that I am going to use in this project is strictly **PHP, Javascript, HTML and CSS.**

I am familiar with MySQL, but I haven't found any information from the web that would answ
er to my question. At least not to my cause.

---

Currently I have this set up

User adds "task" to MySQL "tasks" table with `startdate`and `enddate` (both are in mm/dd/yyyy format) alse `active` which is 1.

I need to create event that checks each day (at midnight) each row in "tasks" table is this day older than `enddate` and if it is update `active` into 0 otherwise leave it as it is.

Comment: Did you check this [What is the best way to delete old rows from MySQL on a rolling basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472167/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-old-rows-from-mysql-on-a-rolling-basis)

Comment: Of course, see [How do I delete rows of data from mysql table automatically with 24 hours after data into table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253746/how-do-i-delete-rows-of-data-from-mysql-table-automatically-with-24-hours-after) post for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this condition:

```
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
So that the whole SQL script looks like this:

CREATE EVENT delete_event
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO BEGIN
      DELETE messages WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END;
```

Comment: Is this function going to loop or do I need to run it manually again after 7 days?

Comment: MySQL uses a special thread called event schedule thread to execute all scheduled events. It performs on schedule time.

Comment: Can this function be set via phpmyadmin?

Comment: You can use either PhpMyAdmin or MySQL command prompt to work with events.

Comment: Do I need to re run this function every time after it has ran? Or did you answer to my question already?

Comment: It performs on schedule time. Not need to run the query.

Comment: Okay that you so much. Can you help me with this matter? You don't need to give me full example thou :)